# How to use polymorphism with TypeScript, Interfaces and Dependency Injections in an Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing a little angular project which has to use dependency injection.
I have the follows structure:

The file **app.component.html** belongs to view and it has the follows directive:

```
<h1>{{nombreServicio}}</h1>
```

The file **prueba.type.ts**, has the interface;

```
export interface PruebaType{
    calcularNombre(): string;
}
```

The file **prueba.service.ts** is the service, which extends the interface.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PruebaType } from './prueba.type' 

@Injectable()
export class PruebaServicio implements PruebaType{
    calcularNombre(): string{
        return "Andy";
    }
}
```

Finally, The **app.components.ts** file uses the functionality of **PruebaServicio** service, but it is no directly with an object of type **PruebaServicio**, rather  with an object of **PruebaType** type (Which is the interface that implements the **PruebaServicio** class):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PruebaType } from './service/Prueba.type';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  nombreServicio: string;

  constructor(private prueba: PruebaType){
    this.nombreServicio = prueba.calcularNombre();
  }

}
```

when I ran the application, I got the mistake:

> Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)

I would like to ask you, if TypeScript has some way to use polymorphism in dependency injection.

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

**-------------------------------------------Added--------------------------------**

I have found an explanation about polymorphism with [Interfaces, TypeScript and Dependency Injections](https://nehalist.io/dependency-injection-in-typescript/#interfacesaregoneaftercompilation):

> Since interfaces are not part of JavaScript they simply disappear
>   after your TypeScript is compiled. Nothing new, but that means we
>   can't use interfaces for dependency injection

Then, the only way to do polymorphism in TypeScript, it is using no abstract class or abstract class like Miguel Pinto said it in their response below. **Does someone think different?**

Comment: Take a look at injection tokens

Comment: Hi 'dcg', thanks for your answer, I have found some examples which uses dependency injection with class, however, I have not seen any example uses interfaces. Also I found in some forums, that I could solve the mistake used the follows code: constructor(@Inject(PruebaServicio) prueba: PruebaType), however it does not like to me because in this case the component class must have the reference to PruebaServicio class, and it is not correct, I am searching the way to break the dependency with the class and only have the reference with the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create a abstract class:

interface PruebaType

```
export interface PruebaType{
    calcularNombre(): string;
}
```

abstract PruebaTypeService :

```
export abstract class PruebaTypeService implements PruebaType{

    abstract calcularNombre(): string;

}
```

Your service

```
@Injectable()
export class PruebaServicio extends PruebaTypeService {
    calcularNombre(): string{
        return "Andy";
    }
}
```

Now you can define your provider :

```
@NgModule({
      ...
      providers: [
        ...,
        {provide: PruebaTypeService , useClass: PruebaServicio }
      ]
})
```

Comment: Hi Miguel, It is a great idea uses an abstract class, but really I am searching doing with interfaces.... Miguel now I have seen you code I arose a doubt, With interfaces, should I add the interface reference to app.modules.ts. file?, I only added the class reference, of this way:   @NgModule({...providers: [PruebaServicio]}).

Comment: Hi @J.Abel, try initialize providers with  {provide: PruebaType, useClass: PruebaServicio }. I don't know if this works.

Comment: Hi Miguel. I tried to user {provide: PruebaType, useClass: PruebaServicio } with interfaces but It did not work, it only works with abstract class.

Comment: What if the `PruebaServicio` class needs an external service to be injected ?